# getJSON returns error 'object is undefined'

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

i have been having this trouble when trying to obtain json data.

lets say i have a file called "projects.json" with the following structure (showing 2 items, the original file has over 100)

```
{"project":[
        {
            "featid":1,
            "ced":12001,
            "x":659770.164751449,
            "y":990679.029463668

        },
        {
            "featid":2,         
            "ced":110002,
            "x":621482.834052153,
            "y":1034455.00718159
        }
]
}
```

when i try to acces the data i get the following error

```
 object is undefined
 length = object.length,
```

this is the function i am using to obtain the data

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var url="json/projects.json";

    $.getJSON(url,{featid: 1},function(data){
        $.each(data.results,function(i,proy){

           $("#output").append('<p>'+proy.ced+'</p>');
        });

    });
});
```

i am missing something? i checked the json file and appears to be valid, so i dont know what could it be.

thank you for your help

Comment: can you try to `alert(data.project.length)` in the callback and see what happens?

Comment: it did work, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data doesn't seem to have a `results` property. Did you mean `project`?

Comment: i cant belive how dumb i was, you are right! i guess i was so frustrated by this that it flew over my head all the time

Answer (score 0):

Ates is right. Instead of using

`$.each(data.results,function(i,proy)`

use `$.each(data.project,function(i,proy)`

as your JSON have project not results. It seems you have copied the code from any example & forgot to change the variable (which is very common) :)

Comment: this was exactly the case, i am starting with jquery and json and took an example and forgot to check in deep.